# Como configurar o SSL de um site que encontra-se localhost com o IIS? (Certificado Auto-Assinado)

Tags: iis, ssl, localhost

Gostaria de adiantar que sou novo com o IIS então me desculpe pelo aspecto leigo e amador. Bem o problema é o seguinte, eu criei um certificado auto-assinado  com o seguinte nome amigável : "*.site.com" cliquei em OK e ele foi associado ao servidor  web. Então em seguida parti para o binding com o site, a tela de edição de ligações ficou assim:

Tela de ligações do site https://i.stack.imgur.com/M97wq.png

Abrindo o browser eu constato que o certificado que criei fez essa ligação ao site, mas me retorna um status de : "NÃO SEGURO"
Estou usando o Drive API na aplicação para manipulação de arquivos no Drive, o login no OAuth nem está funcionando mais, certamente devido a isso.

Estou tendo dois erros:

Quando verifico a aba de segurança do browser, o primeiro é o SAN (subject alternative name ) que ao que parece relata que um pacote contendo um nome alternativo não foi criado no certificado. Quando crio um certificado auto-asssinado ele apenas me demanda um nome amigável, e apenas isso, correto ?
E esse nome alternativo precisa ser um match com o nome do domínio que defino na tela de ligações do site ?

E o segundo erro está relacionado ao "common name invalid"  que eu não consegui explicações que me levassem a sua natureza.

Erros : https://i.stack.imgur.com/72oqv.png

Eu preciso de um norte para a solução deste problema. Desde já, eu agradeço.